# How Can Implement Post-grid- Address checker into My Wordpress Website Contact us page For Address Verify

Tags: php, wordpress, contact-form-7, wordpress-rest-api, street-address

I am Looking for How to Implement "Postgrid" - Address checker into My Wordpress Website Contact us page For Address Verify. i have simple contact us page on my website,

Address Checker Website :  https://www.postgrid.com/address-checker/

`

[image: Contact-us-Page-Form]

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using WordPress the integration should be straightforward if you have access to the HTML of your page. [Here](https://postgrid.readme.io/reference/autocomplete-guide) is the link to the guide that goes over the integration.

First, you need to retrieve your API key from the [developers page](https://app.postgrid.com/dashboard/developers) on the PostGrid dashboard (you'll need to create an account if you haven't made one already). If you're hosting this site on a publicly accessible web page, you'll want to create a "Public" key and add the URL of your website to the list of valid origins. This will ensure nobody can grab your API key and use it on their own website.

Second, you'll need to add special attributes to the tags in your HTML form element for the form. You'll want to add a `data-pg-verify` attribute to your `form` tag and then `data-pg-address-line1` tag to your Physical Address form field. You'll also want to add a `data-pg-full-address-line1` attribute to your `form` tag to ensure that the autocomplete places the complete address into that one form field instead of looking for separate city, province/state, country fields.

Lastly, you can set up elements which will display the errors (if any) with the address (e.g. `data-pg-status`, `data-pg-generic-message`, etc). The linked guide outlines how to do this in detail.